# Log4j2 dosen't create file with RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using RollingFileAppender to make log file daily.

I run my app, and log4j2 create a file name `logs.log`. And i debug a message `log.debug("hello")`, message has writed to `logs.log` file, everything is fine.

And then i change date on my computer to next day, debug a message again. The `logs.log` filename change to `logs_2017-06-05.log`, but log4j2 dosen't create a new log file name `logs.log`. It create `logs.log` file while I must shutdown my app or change date to next day (and debug message again).

Here is my config file.

```
Configutation:
  name: Default
  Appenders:
    RollingFile:
      name: Appender_RollingFile
      fileName: "/Users/jiangxingshang/Downloads/tmp/logs.log"
      filePattern: "/Users/jiangxingshang/Downloads/tmp/logs_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
      immediateFlush: true
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{10} - %msg%n"
      Policies:
        TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          interval: 1
          modulate: true
      DefaultRolloverStrategy:
        max: 2
  Loggers:
    Logger:
      name: com.jxs.springboot
      level: debug
      additivity: false
      AppenderRef:
        ref: Appender_RollingFile
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[Demo on YouTube](https://youtu.be/SVuF0pOESbw)

Comment: Does the behaviour change when you add "DefaultRolloverStrategy max: 2" as described in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Comment: @Aleks I have tried, nothing change.

Comment: hm, that's odd. how old is your version?

Comment: Please can you also adopt the log4j config with your current one

Comment: @Aleks I have updated my post, and the config is current that i am using.

Comment: Thanks. I can try to reproduce it this evening.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @Aleks Thanks, i will try it on other pc.